# Automated integration testing of a client/server Windows desktop application

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, chef-infra, cruisecontrol.net, continuous-delivery

My team is developing a desktop application (mixed C++/Tcl) that is used in a client-server setup. Currently it is Windows-only, but soon we will need to port it to Linux. CruiseControl.NET builds it every night from the source code in SVN and packages it into NSIS installer, but we have no automated tests to run.
It is nearly impossible to add any unit tests, but integration testing of the application is easy, because it is already heavily script-based. 
The main task is to install the app into 3 PCs, configure it (that involves copying some files around), run it, monitor a possible crash, wait till integration testing is done, collect a summary, send emails. It could be done with a bunch of custom PowerShell scripts, but

- In future we will want to add more features and more testing, and
  what used to be a simple script soon blows up (as usual), so I want
  to minimize custom scripting, and if I need to script something, I
  prefer bash/cygwin (I am not familiar with Python or Ruby).
- I want a web dashboard that will report current progress, and if
  something failed - show logs
- I need some supervisor that will monitor the app under test and
  report if it hangs or crashes
- we will need to test it also on Linux
- ideally I would like to orchestrate some test steps between the PCs
  (e.g. run test X on PC1 and test Y on PC2 in parallel, wait till they
  both finish, then run test Z on PC1, while monitoring that nothing
  crashes on PC2 etc)

So, I am looking for a COTS tool/set of tools that will help me to do it and don't have a steep learning curve. Ideally, for free, but if it is really good and has fair pricing, my company may purchase a license.
The process should be triggered from CruiseControl.NET when the NSIS installer is ready, and then perform everything described above. Basically, it should allow at least remote installation of software, running custom scripts and have a web dashboard. 
Apparently, SCCM tools like Chef could be used, but so far neither of them supports a Windows server, only nodes. I would like to avoid setting up a Linux VM just for that, although I can do it, if I have no other choice. Also, Chef seems to be a bit overkill - good for 10k machines, but I have only 3... maybe 5 in future. And I am particularly curious about chances to orchestrate a distributed test.
Most of the similar questions here on StackOverflow and in internets are about web apps, Java containers, Maven etc, and there are just so many tools and plugins for these tools to evaluate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install ccnet on your test machines. Have those ccnet projects listen to a file that gets edited when a new installer is ready. Have the test machines install that new installer and run tests. There you go. ccnet sends emails so there's your basic reporting.

Have the test results get reported into a database via web services using gSOAP(that's what we did).  For linux you can run java cruisecontrol if you must. Write a gSOAP enabled test controller program to report the test results from the test machines. A little c++ app will do. Then write a website(we use ASP.NET) to query the database(Postgresql) and show results. Have the test machines auto update themselves via SVN to get the latest changes to the configuration. Use Nant. Nant is far superior to just using ccnet to run tasks. Nant works through ccnet. Use XML, XSL and CSS with ccnet to make test emails have the information you want(new passes, new failures, SVN differences to code bases, etc...)

Our latest development is putting a big TV in the kitchen with a summary of test results so people can know more readily what they broke!

The first thing I'd get working is a test machine listening for the new installer, installing it, running some basic tests and emailing the results back. Put the ccnet and nant configuration in version control and get that auto updating on the test machine so you don't have to log into every test machine and do an update every time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

This is hugely broad and pretty close to opinion based. Chef can handle steps like deploying the application to the test machines but it isn't a GUI test framework so you would need something else to handle that. Jenkins supports distributing tests to windows hosts so that seems like a good choice on that side of things but it isn't that great at multi-node tests or orchestration between them. I suspect you'll need to write most of this yourself given the requirements.